# Optimal strategy for finding a partition point where the test function has a linear cost

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Given (where $x, t\in\mathbb{N}$) $$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x\lt t\\
0 & x \geq t
\end{cases}
$$

and the cost of computing $f(x)$ is $x$. The problem is then finding $t$ at minimal cost.

Intuitively, you could do an exponential search first, where at each iteration $i\geq 0$ you compute $f(2^i)$, and once you have found the lowest $k$ such that $f(2^k)=0$, you do a binary search within the interval $[f(2^{k-1})+1, f(2^k)-1]$, but I don't know how to prove the optimality of that strategy.

#### Analysis of the provided strategy

The first stage, the exponential search, costs:

$$C_1=\sum_{i=0}^k2^i=2^{k+1}-1$$

Now the interval to binary search is $[z_1, z_{k+1}]=[2^{k-1} + 1, 2^k - 1]$. The second stage, $C_2$, costs:

$$
C_2=\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}(2^k-2^j)=\left(k-\frac{3}{2}\right)2^k+1\\
$$

The reason is because the worst case is going always towards the highest end of the interval (e.g., $f(x)=1$ for every $x\in I$); in other words, when $t=2^k$. At each stage $i\geq 2$ we then compute $f(z_i)$, where $z_i$ is the center of the interval $I_i=[z_{i-1}+1, z_{k+1}]$, which, starting with $z_2=2^k-2^{k-2}$, gives you the sequence $2^k-2^{k-i}, 2\leq i\leq k$.

Finally, the overall costs $C$ is $$C=C_1+C_2=\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)2^k=t\left(\log_2t+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

An equivalent worst case is when $t=2^k-1$ (which also implies going upwards until the end of the original interval), in which case replace $t$ by $t+1$ above; in any case, the absolute cost is the same.

Any better strategy for should improve this worst-case cost.

Comment: If you know $1\le t\le8$ then doing odd numbers in reverse order has a worst case of $19=7+5+3+4$, but bisection has a worst case of $20=5+7+8$

Comment: @Empy2 no if your bisection strategy is by rounding down: 4 + 6 + 7 = 17. Besides, why did you check for 3 and then 4, instead of 3 and then 1? In that case it gives you 16, which is better than bisection.

Comment: A first guess of $4$ divides the range into $1,2,3$ and $4,5,6,7,8$ so it's not bisection.  If $t$ turns out to be $4$ then I know after $7,5,3$ it is either 3 or 4, so I need to test 4.

Comment: @Empy2 I think it's still a bisection because after testing for 4, what I have left (the unknowns) are 1,2,3 to the left and 5, 6, 7, 8 to the right, which is balanced. If I check for $5$, and the result turns out to be $1$, it means that $t$ is higher and I have discarded 5 elements, with 3 elements still to be checked, which isn't balanced.

Comment: Erk, sorry, I wasn't thinking straight

Comment: Do you want to minimize average cost over all $t$ in some range, or maximum cost (again over all $t$ in some range), or some other function? Note that for every certain $t$ there is a strategy which computes $f(t)$, $f(t - 1)$ and nothing else.

Comment: @Smylic I want to minimize the maximum cost given any unbounded $t$ (although an apparently sound strategy is trying to find bounds first, and that's why it sounds logical to me starting by an exponential search). On the other hand, I can't quite see how an strategy for this particular problem can have a better average than other strategy with a better maximum cost. If there are two strategies with important differences in average costs, I would then like to see both if possible, out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT  4 February 2024
I have run programs to find the cheapest options.  I started with the narrowest intervals of one or two numbers, then calculated the cheapest options for wider and wider intervals.

When the aim is to minimize the cost in the worst case, a high early guess can bring down the costs of high numbers, although the cheaper low numbers become more expensive.  This works best when the ratio between the smallest and largest numbers is large.

When the aim is to minimize the average cost, bisection works best when the range (count of possible numbers) is a power of two.
When the range is between $2^{k+1}$ and $3×2^k$ numbers, it seems best to divide the range so the lower piece has a range of $2^k$ numbers.
When the range is between $3×2^k$ and $2^{k+2}$, it seems best to divide the range so the upper piece has a range of $2^{k+1}$ numbers.
This starts to break down with $97$ numbers, which is very near $3×32$.

End of edit

January 25 2024
Too long for a comment.
My suggestion is for an interval from $a+1$ to $a+2^k$.  Test, in turn, $a+\frac342^k,a+\frac242^k$ and $a+\frac142^k$ until only a quarter of the range is possible.  Then apply bisection to the quarter that remains.
If the range is $a+1\le t\le a+2^k$, then bisection costs $$ak+(k-1)2^k+1$$ in the worst case, which is $t=a+2^k-1$ or $t=a+2^k$.
For the method mentioned above, the worst cases for the four quarters are
$$(k-1)a+(4k-6)2^{k-2}+1,(t=a+2^k)\\
ka+(3k-2)2^{k-2}+1,(t=a+\frac342^k)\\
(k+1)a+(2k+1)2^{k-2}+1,(t=a+\frac122^k)\\
(k+1)a+(k+3)2^{k-2},(t=a+\frac142^k)$$

Bisection's worst case is worse than the first two, and the third is worse than the fourth if $k\gt2$.  Bisection is worse than the third case if $$a\lt (2k-5)2^{k-2}$$
If the interval is from $2^k+1$ to $2^{k+1}$, as mentioned by OP, and $k\gt4$, then this method is an improvement in the worst case.

Comment: I haven't been able to replica your four formulas. First, you assume you know $t$ is in the interval $[a+1, a+2^k]$, which implies some previous process have already determined that's the range, are you considering the cost of computing $f(a+1)$ and $f(a+2^k)$, or you assume that such "previous process" have already paid the cost? Or do you assume the previous process has paid the cost for computing $f(a)$ and $f(a+2^k+1)$?

Comment: Same for the quarters, are you considering that you have to pay the cost of computing the three internal points, and thus, regardless of the quarter $t$ belongs to, you have to pay a fixed cost of $3(a+2^{k-1})$? I haven't been able to replicate your formulas and with so many unknowns I don't know where is my mistake.

Comment: Besides, I have added my own analysis of my original proposal to my question.